# AccessDenied when calling the ListQueues operation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, aws-cli

This is quite strange when call list queues command using AWS-CLI with the attached policy not working unless I set value for **Resource** to `arn:aws:sqs:*:*:*`.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sqs:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:*:45*****65:local-*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I expect the below command should return all the Queues that start with local-* but I got AccessDenied.

```
aws sqs list-queues --queue-name-prefix local-*
```

But for the same Queue, I am able to get its attributes.

```
aws sqs get-queue-attributes --queue-url https://us-west-2.queue.amazonaws.com/0****5/local-myqueue --attribute-names All
```

Do I need to changes something in policy or is the behavior of list queue is different?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Actions, Resources, and Condition Keys for Amazon SQS - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_amazonsqs.html), the SQS commands do not accept conditions. Therefore, the `ListQueues()` command either works completely (showing *all* matching queues) or does not return anything (due to Access Denied). The only way to limit which queues are returned is to use the `queue-name-prefix`.

The `Resource` attribute in the policy will determine upon which queue various commands can run, which is why you are able to get attributes for a queue matching `local-*`. If you tried to get the details of a queue named `public-xxx`, it would be denied. (But `ListQueues` operates on the *service*, not a particular queue.)

Comment: Thanks, @John For the answer. it clear to me now but I expect this should work like limiting with `queue-name-prefix` but this also not working. any reason? maybe its also sub flag of ListQueues that's why?

Comment: There is no Condition field available for list-queues, which is where you would normally apply a limitation on the prefix. Feel free to try it -- it would be a Condition with a StringLike, which would force users to provide the prefix or face failure.